# Email validation using Javascript doesn't work with HTML

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I'm trying to let user check if his email adress pass RFC standard, comparing it with regular expression dropped below.

I already checked few examples on console using function responsible for excecute validation test. I'm aware of possibilities that my regex is not ready for, but whenever I tried a few examples on console - it works.

Problem begins when function gets value from included 'text' HTML form.

Using Javascript I also checked how value is interpretated by browser (Simply pasting text into another div) - result is ok.

Why validation doesn't work properly whenever use input value on HTML forms?

```js
const regular = /^[a-z/d]+[/d/w.-]*@(?:[a-z/d-]+[a-z/d-]\.+){1,5}[a-z]{1,3}[a-z]$/i;
test = function(email) {
    if (regular.test(email) == false) {
        alert('Your email adress is not correct. Try again!')
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = document.getElementById('text').value;
        return false;
    } else {
        alert('Match');
        return true;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id='form-structure'>
   <form name='form1' action='#'>
      <label for='email' name='email'>E-mail</label>
      <input type='text' name='text' id='text' placeholder="Enter your email" required>
      <button type='submit' name='submit' onclick="test(document.form1.text)" 
         value='Submit'>Test</button>
   </form>
</div>
<div id='result' style='font-size: 15px'>
</div>
```

Comment: You could use an `<input type="email">` field. Note your "regular" regex is nowhere near RFC compliant — see https://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html — it immediately failed _my_ common address format of `something+something@example.com`, rejecting because of the _plus_, and failed on `name@example.museum` (museum is a valid TLD) Stackoverflow has dozens if not hundreds of questions attempting regex validation of email addresses.

Comment: Szpotu — although you accepted an answer, its statement _"your issue lies in `document.form1.text`. Simple change it to `document.forms.form1.text`"_ is **incorrect**. The issue is _**not**_ that you didn't include `.forms.form1` and used `.form1` alone. The problem is that you didn't use `.value` at the end. Your code would have worked if you used `onclick="test(document.form1.text.value)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this may not be the best of code example, the simple solution to your issue lies in `document.form1.text`. Simple change it to `document.forms.form1.text`.

E.g.

```html
<button type='submit' name='submit' onclick="test(document.forms.form1.text.value)" 
         value='Submit'>Test</button>
```

## EDIT:

I missed the .value before. Now it should work.

Comment: `document.form1.text` and `document.forms.form1.text` both refer to the `<input>` HTML element _**object**_ — neither one refers to the _value_ that has been typed **in** that input control. See Nicolas' answer.

Comment: I used "Copy snippet to answer" from the OP's question and made your change. It fails in exactly the same way, and for the same reason, as the original code; I have therefore downvoted the answer.

Comment: @StephenP, you don't downvote people's answer because it didn't work. That's why SO has a button to mark accepted answer.

Comment: You certainly do downvote wrong answers. Hover your mouse over a downvote button; it says "This answer is not useful". Perhaps you should read the help-center [Why is voting important?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) where it says "...incorrect content falls to the bottom", and the [vote down](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) topic, where it says "Voting down, [...] is how the community indicates which questions and answers are least useful." In my opinion an incorrect answer is not useful and should be downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing the correct value to your function. In your function, the `email` variable is

```
<input type="text" name="text" id="text" placeholder="Enter your email" required></input>
```

What you need to pass to your function is the actual value of the element `#test`. This can be retreive using this selector. You can use this selector inside the function, or directly into the function call. The latter is prefered, like [Mr Zach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63606287/email-validation-using-javascript-doesnt-work-with-html/63606401?noredirect=1#comment112476494_63606401) pointed out. :

```
 document.getElementById('text').value;
```

Also, you regex does not seams right. You are using foward slash ( `/` ) in your digit token and your word token. You need backslash ( `\` ) in that case.

I've also removed the `submit` behaviour of your form, this is to facilitate debugging. It was not the cause of your problem.

```js
const regular = /^[a-z\d]+[\d\w.-]*@(?:[a-z\d-]+[a-z\d-]\.+){1,5}[a-z]{1,3}[a-z]$/i;

var test = function(email) {
    if (regular.exec(email) == null) {
        alert('Your email adress is not correct. Try again!')
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = document.getElementById('text').value;
        return false;
    } else {
        alert('Match');
        return true;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id='form-structure'>
   <form name='form1' action=''>
      <label for='email' name='email'>E-mail</label>
      <input type='text' name='text' id='text' placeholder="Enter your email" required>
      <button type='button' name='submit' onclick="test(document.getElementById('text').value)" 
         value='Submit'>Test</button>
   </form>
</div>
<div id='result' style='font-size: 15px'>

</div>
```

Comment: Should pass the value to the function. Not let the function find the element and then get the value. If you let the function find the element, you lock your function to only work on this element.

Comment: that's a good, point. Maybe i can use the `document.getElementById('text').value` selector directly in the function call.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `this.form.text.value` which doesn't require a full DOM ID scan for something adjacent to the button (or `document.form1.text.value` as OP started with).  Although given the value of the `label` it seems the name of the input *should* be `email` (not `text`)